# How to create pop-up widgets and filters in icCube Reporting version 6.5?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

How to create menu’s & filters that appear and disappear by pressing a button? The icCube 5.x demo showed how to have widgets appear and disappear on a button click. This technique has been used by me in project dashboards (see image).

How could the same be achieved in the latest icCube reporting version (6.5)?

Images & how it works:

- press filter icon -> filters and embellishments appear
- press X icon -> fall disappears again

[image: example pop-up functionality]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version there is no native support for popup widgets, but you could achieve the same functionality by using a JS action.

Attach a CSS class to the widget and use toggle functionality. I've created an example report that demonstrates how it works: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z7xjfcY-G8rH8KJCcQb9XGUJk37ax1Q7

Comment: This is perfect - simple and effective. Thnak you very much.

Comment: --> just one more remark. I would like the button to really toggle. In my example I would like to change the fontawesome icon: press once (icon X), press again (icon Filter). How can you achieve that in your example?

Comment: --> another remark. The intial setting should be that all popup widgets are hidden. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You could add a CSS rule to the Configuration -> report CSS. Something like: .widget-class {display: none}